# SQL Server 2012 connection

Tags: sql-server-2012

When connection to sql server why do I need to write "\SQLEXPRESS" at the end of my server name. On my old PC I did not have to write that.
For example:

```
On my old PC I used to write: "."
On my new PC I have to write: ".\SQLEXPRESS"
```

What do I do to have it like it was on my old PC?

Thank you.

Comment: it's the `name` of the DB instance.  Things are different from SQLSrver 2000

Comment: @TMcKeown On my old pc I used the same version of SQL server

Comment: you had an instance name on there.

Comment: @TMcKeown everything is the same as it was on my old PC

Comment: SQL Server was installed as the default instance on your old PC but not on your new PC.